# requirejs http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to get my hands on require.js which is new for me but I cannot have it work. After having followed some simple tutorials for beginners, I proceeded to create my first (fairly simple project).

I am using visual studio 2013 (as I am a .net guy)
This is a quick way on my file structure

```
./content
    /*a bunch of css files*
./Scripts
    /jquery-1.9.1.js
    /sandbox.js  (!! my library !!)

.index.html (on the root)
.app.js (on the root)
```

Here is my module: sandbox.js

```
//sandbox.js
require.config({
    paths:{
       "jquery":"/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1"
    }
});

define(["jquery"], function($){

       var show_name = function(n){
           alert(n);
       };

       return{
          showName : display_name
       }   

});
```

And now in the app.js I make use of the module sandbox.js. Here is how

```
// app.js
require(["/Scripts/sandbox"], function(sandbox){
    sandbox.showName('John');    
});
```

Finally in the index.html, I load my require.js file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/Scripts/require.js" data-main="/Scripts/sandbox"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run this code I get the error

**0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Script error for: /Scripts/sandbox
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror**

This error occurs in the app.js

```
require(['/Scripts/sandbox'], function (sandbox) {
    sandbox.showName("John");
});
```

Obviously there is something wrong in my way of caling and using the module sandbox.js. But I cannot figure out what the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you should use `define` instead of `require`

Answer (score 3):

- First of all, you should change all `/Scripts/*` to `Scripts/*`.
- Second thing is, you have set your data-main to `Scripts/sandbox`, that is, your baseUrl is set to `Scripts/`. So your `app.js` should look like:

```js
require(["sandbox"], function(sandbox){
    sandbox.showName('John');
});
```

And your `sandbox.js` should be:

```js
require.config({
    paths:{
       "jquery":"jquery-1.9.1"
    }
});

define(["jquery"], function($){

       var show_name = function(n){
           alert(n);
       };

       return{
          showName : display_name
       }   

});
```

Answer (score -2):

I have finally managed to make it work. 
In my app.js, it should be "['Scripts/sandbox.js']" and not "['Scripts/sandbox']".
Hope this can help any one else with the same issue

Comment: The RequireJS documentation is clear that you should not add `.js` at the end of module names.

Comment: Then I don't know why it is working now. This is how I am consuming my sandbox module in the app.js :  require( ['Scripts/sandbox.js'], function(sandbox) { sandbox.showName("Jack") } ); with the extension .js And every thing works

Comment: I note in your answer here and in your comment you have the module name `"Scripts/sandbox.js"`, whereas in your question it is `"/Scripts/sandbox"`. Note the presence of a leading `/` in your question and its absence in your answer. Did you really just add `.js` or did you also  add a leading `/`?

Comment: thanks for pointing out. I did not realize it at first since I was playing around, trying to figure out what could go wrong. I must have removed it without even thinking. And yes if I put back the leading / it's not working